# How to associate XML file with XSD file in Eclipse for autocomplete?

Tags: eclipse, xsd

Does anyone know what plug-in I need with Eclipse to associate an XML file with an XSD schema so that autocomplete is enabled?  And also what steps need to be taken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need any plug-ins.  Eclipse does it automatically provided that the following xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation attribute is defined.

if you want it to complete inside a tag you need to hit control space